# How can I create Custom Extension Attribute in Azure AD B2C using the portal and need to return in the user claims?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have to create user attribute which can contain multiple values.

E.g. I have an email **'test@gmail.com'** and need to add a customized attribute called as **'Project'** which assumes to be an array such as '**[Project1, Project2,...]**'. i.e every user associated with variable project list and this need to be return with the claims.

**User 1 
 email : 'test1@gmail.com', project : ['Project1','Project2']**

**User 2 
 email : 'test2@gmail.com', project : ['Project1','Project3','Project4']**

**Q1)** Is it possible to create customization in attribute to store such array values Or Is there any other method to handle multiple projects data to a single email account.

**Q2)** If possible can I be able to retrieve the attribute data in the token claims ?

(I have tried with creating custom attribute. But it will handle with a string type value only.)

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comma spearated list in claim value and then tokenize the string claim in your application.

The built in way of doing it is using PageLayouts. You can modify user input type to CheckBoxMultiSelect and provide options there. The claim you get is a comma seperated value of different options selected by user.

[image]

[image]

**The use case looks like something which can be done by a database mapping between project table and user table. Are you sure custom extension attribute is the right place for it?**

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not sure about the extension attributes. I had tried with custom attributes but assigned a single value such as **Project : Project1**. So I had got return claim as "extension_project": "Project1". But my application scope is to handle multiple values.

Comment: I updated the answer, it should help. Extension = custom attributes